# access of variables from one test to another using unittest in python

Tags: python, python-unittest

I wrote the following code as below:

```
#base.py

import sys
import unittest

class BaseClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp():
       print"in base script"
    def tearDown():
       print"in teardown"
```

This is the test script:

```
#test.py

import sys 
import unittest
from base import *

class demo_script(BaseClass):
  def setUp(self):
    self.flag = False
    self.abc = None
    super(demo_script, self).setUp()

  def test_before(self):
    self.abc = 5
    ## reboot occurs here and system context is saved

  def test_after(self):
    if self.abc == 5:
         print"Pass"
    else:
         print"fail"

  def tearDown(self):
    print"clean"
```

The test is failing as it is unable to access the variable self.abc.
How can the local variable be accessed in both the tests i.e. test_before() and test_after()?

Answer (score 0):

Test runners such as Nose don't ensure test method running sequence. So if you set `self.abc` in `test_before` it's not sure that `test_after` is run after `test_before`.

Anyway, sharing state between test methods other than defined in `setUp` is a bad idea -- the tests should be isolated.

So merge the test methods into one.